# Install docker compose as any other plugin

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

If docker compose V2 is a plugin, and docker plugins can be installed from a registry with the `docker plugin install` subcommand, why isn't the very docker-compose plugin published as such so that `docker plugin install docker/compose` could work?

Why the installation instructions point to downloading a release blob from github and manually placing it inside the `$DOCKER_CONFIG/cli-plugins` folder instead?

Answer (score 0):

They are different kinds of plugins. One is a CLI plugin that interfaces directly with the `docker` command. The other are specific extensions to the volumes, networking, and other parts of the `dockerd` engine that runs on the container host. Installing a CLI plugin directly is an interim workflow, designed for developers, while packaging is finished.

With current supported releases, you can see the `docker-compose-plugin` package in the [docker repositories](https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/buster/pool/stable/amd64/) which would be my preferred installation method.